# SAS how to color specific rows with ODS and proc report

Tags: sas, ods

I plan to color some rows with specific conditions (male and name starts with 'J') in a table class:

```
ods excel close;
ods excel file='c://class.xlsx';
data class; set sashelp.class; 
  if substr(name,1,1)='J' and sex='M' then tt=1; 
run;
proc report data=class nowd;
 columns sex  height weight name age tt;
 compute tt;
  if tt=1 then call define(_row_, "style", "style=[backgroundcolor=yellow]");
 endcomp;
run;
ods _all_ close;
```

it does not work, and just wonder how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not define tt, the default use will be a analysis column.  Thus `tt` will not be available in the `compute`, instead it would be `tt.<statistic>`.

Regardless, add a `define` statement to indicate `tt` is for display and the conditional styling will be applied correctly.

```
proc report data=class ;
 columns sex  height weight name age tt;

 define tt / display;   /* explicitly specify column usage */

 compute tt;
  if tt=1 then call define(_row_, "style", "style=[backgroundcolor=yellow]");
 endcomp;
run;
```

[image]